# Nginx content-security-policy not being acknowledged

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I have an Nginx WordPress site and a few proxy redirects configured. I have tried adding a CSP header to my nginx.conf, my WordPress site/proxy redirect site files, and to both. For testing purposes, I have it set to the following (where example.com is my domain):

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com;
                                    script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.wp.com  https://ssl.google-analytics.com https:/$
                                    img-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://example.com https://ssl.google-analytics.c$
                                    style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://example.com https://fonts.googleapis.com$
                                    font-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://example.com https://blog.hellodadiam.worl$
                                    frame-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://example.com https://assets.zendesk.com h$
                                    object-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' https://example.com 'unsafe-inline' https://example.com;"
                                    always;
```

When I take a look at my browser console, I still get this CSP:

```
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self';
```

Strangely enough, this seems to not affect Firefox, even though it gets the same header as the other browsers.

For the proxies, they work fine when I connect to them directly so it must be something with Nginx.

Is there something I'm missing or did I configure something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was just panicking. I took a look at the Nginx config again and I found an options file that Certbot auto-added. In there was the locked down CSP that I was looking for. I just commented out that line and everything worked fine.

Certbot added this line in the site config file:

```
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
```

And in that file was the CSP that i saw on my browser:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; frame-ancestors 'none'; script-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self';";
```